# Test cases for span tag

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular7

I want to write some test cases for `<span>` class which is present inside the `<div>`. I tried with some possibilities but couldn't figure it out. Below test case getting failed.

`sample.component.html`:

```html
<div *ngIf="element.status == 'Pending'" class="status-pending">
  <span class="part-status">Pending</span>
</div>
<div *ngIf="element.status == 'Approved'" class="status-pending">
  <span class="part-status">Approved</span>
</div>
```

`sample.spec.ts file`:

```
it('should have following status of Inspection',()=>{
  fixture.detectChanges();
  let debugTest = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.part-status')); 
  let elementTest = debugTest[0].nativeElement;
  //let elementTest1 = debugTest[1].nativeElement;
  const content = elementTest.textContent;
  console.log(content ); // In console i am getting empty [].
  expect(content).toContain('Pending');
  //expect(content).toContain('Approved');
});
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the `element.status`, the DOM element you are trying to access might actually not be available, which is the most likely cause for error here. Also I would change the way you access the DOM elements, just go via `fixture.nativeElement.querySelector`, this always seems to work without any issues for me.

Assuming the `element.status` is set to `Pending`, a test case could look like this:

```
it('check pending state', () => {
  let pendingDiv = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.status-pending');
  expect(pendingDiv).toBeTruthy();

  let pendingSpan = pendingDiv.querySelector('.part-status');
  expect(pendingSpan).toBeTruthy();
  expect(pendingSpan.textContent).toBe('Pending');            
});
```

> Have a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-htkg8a?file=app%2Fdummy%2Fdummy.component.spec.ts),
>   it has two test cases, one for each element status.